# LARAVEL Where to save edited slugs?

Tags: php, laravel

If I have tables products and seller. Seller have slug "seller-a" and he changes slug to "seller-b" now I want to url "seller-a" be 301 to "seller-b" what is best way to achieve this.

1.One solution is to create table productDeleteSlugs but then I need to create n tables for all entities that uses slugs(seller etc.)

2.Second solution is to create master table for all slugs of all entities but then table will have millions of rows and I don't think this is good idea.

What is yours solution ?

Comment: second solution is good you will need to have a cron or something that will remove older unvisited slugs thus maintaining a small size table

Comment: good idea :) tnx for comment